# Sitecore 7.2 users getting locked in Media Library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-media-library, media-library

Occasionally, users click into the media library while in the content tree in the content editor, and it winds up presenting them with only the media library tree afterward, with no option to pop up a level. Why might this be happening? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure the editor has not switched to Media Library mode, from the options at the bottom of the window: http://imgur.com/Eo7pXWN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default setting for all new users in Sitecore is to not show the full tree. This is a common problem I see all the time.

Have each of your users do the following:

1. Click the Sitecore logo in the content editor (top left corner)
2. Select the **Application Options** menu
3. Select the **View** tab
4. Check the box for **Show Entire Content Tree**
5. Refresh the browser to reload the content editor and the tree should now be fixed